# What are all the quotes in the Far Cry 3 loading screens?

Tags: far-cry-3

I've noticed that after finishing a story related mission you usually get 1 or more quotes from what I believe is  Alice in Wonderland.

I was wondering, is there a list available with all the quotes in the loading/transition screens?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are the quotes:

"*In another moment down went Alice after it, never once considering how
in the world she was to get out again.*"
[image: In another moment down went Alice after it, never once considering how in the world she was to get out again.]

"*'I like the Walrus best,' said Alice: 'because you see he was a LITTLE
sorry for the poor oysters.'*

*'He ate more than the Carpenter, though,' said Tweedledee.*"
[image: 'I like the Walrus best,' said Alice: 'because you see he was a LITTLE sorry for the poor oysters. 'He ate more than the Carpenter, though,' said Tweedledee.]

"*'Oh, you can't help that,' said the Cat: 'we're all mad here. I'm mad.
You're mad.'*

*'How do you know I'm mad?' said Alice.*

*'You must be,' said the Cat, 'or you wouldn't have come here.'*"
[image: 'Oh, you can't help that,' said the Cat: 'we're all mad here. I'm mad. You're mad.' 'How do you know I'm mad?' said Alice. 'You must be,' said the Cat, 'or you wouldn't have come here.']

"*'Have you guessed the riddle yet?' the Hatter said, turning to Alice
again.*

*'No, I give it up,' Alice replied: 'what's the answer?'*

*'I haven't the slightest idea,' said the Hatter.*"
[image: 'Have you guessed the riddle yet?' the Hatter said, turning to Alice again. 'No, I give it up,' Alice replied: 'what's the answer?' 'I haven't the slightest idea,' said the Hatter.]

"*'What do you mean by that?' said the Caterpillar sternly. 'Explain
yourself!'*

*'I can't explain MYSELF, I'm afraid, sir' said Alice, 'because I'm not
myself, you see.'*

*'I don't see,' said the Caterpillar.*"
[image: 'What do you mean by that?' said the Caterpillar sternly. 'Explain yourself!' 'I can't explain MYSELF, I'm afraid, sir' said Alice, 'because I'm not myself, you see.' 'I don't see,' said the Caterpillar.]

"*'Everything's got a moral, if only
you can find it.'*"
[image: 'Everything's got a moral, if only you can find it.']
In the "*If only you can find it*" part, the words "kill", "fuck" and "find" are shown alternately until settling at "find" in the end.

The screen captures are from this Youtube video:

I got the text from Project Gutenberg:
[Alice's Adventures in Wonderland by Lewis Carroll](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/11)
[Through the Looking-Glass by Lewis Carroll](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/12)

All quotes are originally from [Alice's Adventures in Wonderland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice%27s_Adventures_in_Wonderland), except the second quote ("*I like the Walrus best..*"), which is from [Through the Looking-Glass, and What Alice Found There.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Through_the_Looking-Glass)

Comment: Great answer thanks. you'll get the bounty in a few days so i can give others the oppurtunity to make a more in depth answer